# Could someone help me identify this kanji?

Tags: kanji

[image]

There is 格, then that kanji that i can't recognise, and then 内 and 庫. 
What kanji is that one in the between the first and the third one?

Comment: This is simply 格納庫 'hangar' - there's only three letters here.

Comment: Did you not notice that this was answered last time you asked?